# Safari 4 is still installed after Mac OS update installed Safari 5 as well. What to do?

Tags: mac, safari

I have updated from OS 10.6.3 to 10.6.5 and  the download automatically updated to Safari 5. I now see that Safari 4 is still installed. What is best to do? Uninstall Safari 4, and how shall I do it? In  the applications tab there is only one Safari icon, but in Spotlight you can find both of them. Thank you.

Comment: Where in your Applications folder is Safari 4 installed? What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it by deleting its application bundle. If you observe anything to break, roll back using Time Machine. If you are concerned about deleting it breaking things, and you aren't using Time Machine (why not?), then it hurts nothing to leave it there.

Comment: Also take a look at `AppCleaner`, which is quite good at finding straggling files for an application that may not be deleted with the bundle.